# How to echo javascript into current html page from external php file

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say I'm currently browsing mypage.html, which in its header has a link to the following js file:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

In `jsfile.js`, there's a function `keyup()` that is executed when the user types something into `#searchbar`, whose value is then stored in `search = $(#searchbar).val();`

I then pass this value on to `search.php` as follows:

```
$.post( "search.php", { searchval: search }, function(sentdata){
    console.log(sentdata);
});
```

where the content of `search.php` reads:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[searchval])){
        $search = $_POST[searchval];
    echo "input value is $search";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('its working') </script> ";
}
?>
```

However, instead of an alert pop up (or anything else that would normally be executed in JS), the second echo simply prints " alert('its working') " into the console. 
How can I modify search.php to allow it to inject actual js into myfile.html? Note that I've also tried wrapping the js code in  tag.

Related question: why is it that when I omit `console.log(sentdata)`, `search.php` does no longer echo anything into the console?

Comment: can you please share your input tag inside HTML?

Comment: search/check for `jQuery.ajax` with `dataType: 'jsonp'` option. http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can modify search.php to allow it to inject actual js in myfile.html?

First of all, you need to modify your javascript file:

```
$.post( "search.php", { searchval: search }, function(sentdata){
    eval(sentdata);
});
```

And no need for javascript tags, just echo a valid Javascript code:

```
if(isset($_POST[searchval])){
    echo "alert('its working');";
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: despite the provided explanation, I don't quite see why that first modification was necessary. isn't the purpose of function(sentdata) simply to return something on successful execution of $.post?

Comment: @ephemeral You get a string from server. Javascript doesn't know whether it's a code or not. You must execute it, `eval` is used for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
$.post( "search.php", { searchval: search }, function(data){
    alert(data);  // this will alert the data which will print on search.php
});
```

and in the php file echo the data you want to print like

```
if(isset($_POST[searchval])){
    echo 'its working. i got'.$_POST[searchval];
}
```